# define myself'd file type using CFBundleDocumentTypes

Tags: iphone

I know I can define file type using in appinfo.plist
such as zip, pdf etc

Is it possible define any type with special extension, such as '.mydatafiletype' or '.datafiletype'

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. The [`documentation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010411-SW1) clearly states so.

Comment: Thanks. In 'com.example.myformat', 'example is' my app apple id?

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can.
 Generally, you need to set `UTExportedTypeDeclarations` property in `info.plist` file.

The post here: [How do I associate file types with an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application) 
Gives you a sample to do it.

Hope this helps.